# Can't create constructor for template type with template type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, generics, constructor

Disclaimer: I'm very new to C++.

I have a `Container` class and an `Item` class. Both of them are generic with the same `Type`:

**container.h:**

```
template<typename Type>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(Item<Type> item);
}
```

**container.cpp:**

```
#include "container.h"
#include "item.h"

template<typename Type>
Container<Type>::Container(Item<Type> item)
{
}
```

The problem is that an error is showing on the Container's constructor:

> no instance of overloaded function "Container::Container"
> matches the specified type

[constructor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmQI2.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: In general templates are fully implemented in their header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is done like this, container.h

```
template<typename Type>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(const Item<Type>& item)
    {
       // implementation goes here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create container.tpp (template file)
and write implementation of your class method in
container.tpp

Like this:

**container.h**:

```
template<typename Type>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(Item<Type> item);
}
#include" container.tpp" //write this at the end of container.h
```

In container.tpp

**container.tpp:**

```
template<typename Type>
Container<Type>::Container(Item<Type> item)
{
}
```